# Do something after tab is visible in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a function in javascript (i'm using jquery) after that my tab is it showed.
So this it he code that i'm testing:

```
$("#tabsL").html(data).tabs("destroy").tabs({
    select:function(event, ui){
        var section = $(ui.tab).attr("href");
        var foo = section.split("-");
        var looking_for = "#slideshow-carousel-"+foo[1]+"-"+foo[2]+" ul li img";
        var imgangefd = $(looking_for)[0];
        $(imgangefd).click();
    }
});
```

but imgangefd need to be visible to get a click.
So my question is what can i do something after the tab is clicked and loaded and visible?

Thanks for any clue!
Roberto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the `tabsshow` event:

```
$( "#tabControl" ).bind( "tabsshow", function(event, ui) {
  //...
});
```

To check for a specific tab, look at what panel was opened (each tab opens a panel):

```
var panel = $(ui.panel);
```